# detail view not updated when Passing data from table view to detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a table view to display an array of data and I would like to pass the value to update Labels and image view in the detail view controller. I actually created a custom cell and I loaded it in the Table view and on selecting a row i pushed a new  custom view controller with labels and ImageView. I would like to use the values of selected cell to be displayed in the labels in custom view controller. The code compiles but the only thing is that the Labels and image view in the detail view doesn't get updated. I just don't know where I'm going wrong…I'm pretty much stuck with for quite sometime. below is the code in my app…

```
code in table view…

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [tableData count]; 
 }
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


if (cell == nil)
{


    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}

cell.LocationLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.TimeLabel.text = [time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
   }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
TrafficDetailViewViewController *trailsController = [[TrafficDetailViewViewController alloc] init];

trailsController.trafficImage.image = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
trailsController.LocationLable.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 //transfering control to detail view
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES];
 }
```

TrafficTableViewViewController.m

```
   @synthesize trafficImage = _trafficImage;
   @synthesize LocationLable = _LocationLable;
```

in the above code TrafficDetailViewController is a custom view controller I've created and it contains labels and UIImage. Please let me know where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, may it will solve your issue. the problem is that you are setting the properties after pushing the controller which is wrong. try the below code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    TrafficDetailViewViewController *trailsController = [[TrafficDetailViewViewController alloc] init];
    trailsController.trafficImage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    trailsController.LocationLable = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //transfering control to detail view
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES];
 }
```

**EDIT**

.h File
in .m File

Add the synthesizer if you are not adding yet.

```
@synthesize trafficImage = _trafficImage;
@synthesize LocationLable = _LocationLable;
```

Also Edit one more thing when you are trying to push Your TrafficDetailViewController

then please assign image to trafficImage.image not to trafficImage and string to LocationLabel.text because trafficImage is an ImageView not an Image and LocationLable is a label not string.So replace your line with following code

```
trailsController.trafficImage.image = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
trailsController.LocationLable.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**POST EDIT**

in .h file

```
@interface TrafficDetailViewViewController : UIViewController 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *trafficImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LocationLable; 
//Add these two more properties in TrafficDetailViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *locationString;

@end
```

in .m File:

```
@synthesize trafficImage = _trafficImage;
@synthesize LocationLable = _LocationLable;
@synthesize image = _image;
@synthesize locationString = _locationString;
```

in viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.trafficImage.image = _image;
    self.LocationLabel.text = _locationString;
}
```

and then in Previous viewController where you have written the push code for TrafficDetailviewController replace the following code with yours

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    TrafficDetailViewViewController *trailsController = [[TrafficDetailViewViewController alloc] init];
    trailsController.image = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    trailsController.locationString = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //transfering control to detail view
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES];
 }
```

The reason behind this is like your ViewController is not loaded before pushing and we are trying to set imageView.image and Lable.text which I think is causing the issue. Please try this and let me know is it working now?

Enjoy coding!!

Comment: I've made the change already…but it still doesn't get updated….:(

Comment: then the cause of issue is different. Try to debug the code. Go to TrafficDetailViewViewController viewDidLoad: method and try to get value of the properties used. Let me know if they are nil or have value?

Comment: Can you add code from your TrafficDetailViewViewController file?

Comment: I haven't added any code in that except this in the .h file….`@interface TrafficDetailViewViewController : UIViewController   
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *trafficImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LocationLable;

@end
`

Comment: @iProgrammer the values to the properties are not set in the TrafficDetailViewViewController. can you brief on how to set them...

Comment: Change the refrence from weak to strong. Like @property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView * trafficImage;. Please see my editted answer for more details.

Comment: @iProgrammer I've made all the changes you said but I'm still stuck with it….Is there anything that I should add in the viewdidLoad method in TrafficDetailViewController….?

Comment: Are you using storyboards or xib??

Comment: Check My POST EDIT block of code. Ithink the issue is assigning the image to UIIMageView and UILable before loading the view is not correct. So try the new code I hope now our efforts will not be in vain..!!!

Comment: @iProgrammer I'm actually using both storyboard and xib…only the TrafficDetailViewViewController and the table view cell(SimpleTableCell) are separate xib files….

Comment: @iProgrammer my application crashes showing an exception in the viewdidload method of TrafficDetailViewController on launch after I made the changes said in the second edit….:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41793/discussion-between-iprogrammer-and-yaitsme)

Comment: got the reason of crash.. Actualy mistakenly I have written trafficImageView instead of trafficImage. please update it to self.trafficImage.image = _image;

Comment: Two things. First, there's no need to use "@synthesize" any more, that's done for you automatically. Second, it appears from what the OP has in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the value being passed to _image is  the image name (a string), not an image.

Comment: @rdelmar thank you for the correction and what should I do pass the image itself instead of the image name…??

Comment: @YaItsMe, Pass the same thing you used in cellForRowAtIndexPath, [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]. Or, you could pass the name, and set the image in trailsController (in that case you would change the property, image, to something like imageName and make it a string).

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your code that creates and pushes the trailsController. Create it, set the properties, and THEN push it.

That may or may not be the cause of your problem. Next you need to debug the trailsController. What do you do with the properties trafficImage and locationTable? Do you have custom setters, or do you use them in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods? Post the relevant code from those methods in the other view controller.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get the first part please can you explain in detail I'm still a beginner...

Comment: @Duncan wants you to move this line: [[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES]; after that one: trailsController.LocationLable = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I haven't done much with the detail viewController other than connecting the created outlets for the imageView and labels….

Comment: @greg thanks for the explanation…;) but still its not getting updated…:(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be in the way you instantiate TrafficDetailViewViewController, using alloc init. This will create a controller with an empty view, and is probably not the one you want to push on screen. If you created this controller's view in a xib, then you should be using initWithNibName:bundle: instead of init. If you created it in a storyboard, then you should use [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"]. This line could be a problem too, I can't tell what you're trying to do here:

```
trailsController.LocationLable = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Is LocationLable a label, or is it a string? To populate a label, you should pass the string to the next controller, and have that controller set the text of its own label.

Comment: I think I getting around it somewhat here…as you said I'm using a xib so I'll try with the initwithNibName and let you know if it works….;)

Comment: I set bundle to "nil". still the outlets in detail view are not getting updated…:( Please help

Comment: @YaItsMe, please update your question to show what you now have in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and what you have in trailsController where  you set the image and the label.

Comment: I have edited the code above in the question as asked…Please let me know if there is anything else that i should do….Thanks for the help..;)